# Yocto recipe dependcy

Tags: linux, dependencies, yocto, bitbake

I would like to ask for an advice regarding Yocto recipes dependencies.

I want to have recipes, inheriting my provider.bbclass with some logic to collect files for future processing.

I want to have one more recipe (lets call it collector) to take these files and generate some output from them into the rootfs. So this recipe should depend on the recipes above.

But I don't want to hardcode the DEPENDS variable. Is there any way of letting the collector recipe wait for all recipes inheriting provider.bbclass?

What I have tried was to define a PROVIDERS variable in the provider.bbclass and assigned

```
PROVIDERS += "${PN"}
```

And in the collector recipe, I tried to

```
inherit provider.bbclass
DEPENDS += "${PROVIDERS}
```

But that obviously doesn't work, because DEPENDS variable seems to be parsed at the beginning.

Second idea I have is to not use the collector recipe and instead let the recipes including the provider.bbclass to run the generation. But only once and at the end of the process. Which I have no clue how to do and if it is possible.

I will be grateful for any advice or pointer on solution.

Thank you,
Michal

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to accomplish this. Classes and recipes are parsed and evaluated separately at the recipe level.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. But still I was thinking it is better first to ask some people smarter than me. Thank you.